# Horizontal lines of different thickness above and below text which span the entire page.

Tags: sectioning

I am trying to make section headers like in [this resume](http://www.lifeclever.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/10/04_finishing_touches.gif).  I want one line above the text and one below with the above line thicker than the one below.  The lines also need to span the entire page.  I have tried something like

`\rule{\textwidth}{1px}\\
Heading\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.5px}\\`

but the spacing is way off.  There is too much spacing between the lines and the text.  How can I make it look like in the example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\newcommand\myheading[1]{\par
  \bigskip
  \hrule height 1pt
  \kern 2pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\textbf{#1}\hfil}
  \kern 2pt
  \hrule height 0.5pt
  \kern\medskipamount}
```

We close a paragraph, leave a vertical space and draw a 1pt thick rule; after it we leave a small space (customize it to suit you) and print the heading, with another small space after it. A 0.5pt thick rule and another space.

Four tricks are used in this low level code: (1) a vertical space inserted via `\kern` won't be used by TeX to break a page, so the only permissible place for breaking is at the `\bigskip` preceding the heading; (2) `\hbox` doesn't start the horizontal mode and no glue (so no place for page breaking) is inserted before or after a box contributed to the main vertical list; (3) a `\kern` in vertical mode produces a vertical space that is fixed in length; (4) an `\hrule` without a `width` specification extends to cover the widest box in the vertical list (here the `\hbox to \textwidth{...}`. A consequence of the page break rules is that no page break can intervene between the heading and the paragraph following it (provided it doesn't insert penalties, which may happen if the following item is a list such as `itemize`).

Gonzalo's solution based on **titlesec** is very clean, but sometimes a low level code is faster, provided we understand it. `:-)`

Comment: This works great.  Can you give me some insight into what is going on in this code?  What does the kern command do here?

Comment: `\kern 2pt` gives an incompressible space but there is a trick : in horizontal mode you get an horizontal displacement (movement) and in vertical mode you get an vertical displacement. Another trick, TeX can't cut a line on a `\kern`. In math mode you have  `\mkern`.

Comment: Thank you.  After playing around with both solutions, I wound up using this.  As it is lower level, I find it much easier to control the layout/spacings.

Comment: Helpful comment to anybody reading...I would throw a `\strut` near the `#1` to make sure all lines are equidistant from each other (my aesthetic preference). If one heading is "Rabbits" and another one is "Elephants", the `hbox` heights will be different because the latter has to account for the depth of "p".

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `titlesec` package to redefine the way `\section` behaves:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\setlength\parskip{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\hrule height 1pt\vspace{2pt}}[\hrule height 0.2pt]
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{0pt}{10pt}

\begin{document} 

\section{EDUCATION}
\lipsum[1]
\section{LEGAL EXPERIENCE}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: as requested in a comment, here's the modification of the code that allows to use `\so`, from the `soul` package, for the section titles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\setlength\parskip{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\hrule height 1pt\vspace{2pt}\so{#1}}[\hrule height 0.2pt]
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{0pt}{10pt}

\begin{document} 

\section{EDUCATION}
\lipsum[1]
\section{LEGAL EXPERIENCE}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a good idea.  How can I combine this with `\so` from the soul package to make the section titles' characters have more spacing?

Comment: @Justin J Stark: you can use `\section{\so{EDUCATION}}` (after loading `soul` in the preamble) or `\section[EDUCATION]{\so{EDUCATION}}` if a table of contents will be generated.

Comment: @Justin J Stark: for an automatic solution see my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent.  I think using `\section` makes more sense.  Thank you very much.

Comment: letter spacing can be obtained also with **microtype**, the command is `\textls`.