# A new paragraph followed by a big skip

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, lengths, parskip

Here is the code I am using to place a heading with a line above and below the text, from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20869/horizontal-lines-of-different-thickness-above-and-below-text-which-span-the-entir).

```
\newcommand{\rheading}[1]
{
    \par
    \bigskip
    \hrule height 1pt
    \kern 5pt
    \hbox to \textwidth{\textbf{\mediumletterspace{#1}}\hfil}
    \kern 5pt
    \hrule height 0.2pt
    \kern\smallskipamount
}
```

However, with the `\par` at the beginning, there is `\parskip` vertical space followed by a `\bigskip` vertical space.  I want to make this skip the same, regardless of the length of `\parskip`.  How do I accomplish this?  Also, if I get rid of the `\par`, there is no vertical skip at all and not even a line break.  Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `\addvspace\bigskipamount` (or with braces around `\bigskipamount` if this is just a single token; it doesn't make any difference).  it's always prudent to insert `\par`.

the reason there is no vertical space -- or even a line break -- if you don't include `\par` is that the `\vspace` doesn't take effect until there is actually a transition to vertical mode, which will actually happen at the next "normal" line break.  this is sometimes used as a method for spacing down a bit before the next line when you're not sure exactly where the line will end.  similarly, placing `\newpage` in the middle of a text line will start a new page as soon as the current line ends normally.